# Is there a way to have three outcomes of an Excel IF statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to have an if statement that can write out the answers.
"Risk/Reward is good"
"Risk/Reward is mediocre"
"Risk/Reward is bad"
I have thought about using Vlookup, but then I have to have the answers written down, and I just want the output to be automatic correlating to the cell that shows the Risk/Reward.
Is this possible with an IF-statement? Or do I have to use another formula, in that case which?

I will add a picture of the sheet to show what I want.
[image]
Risk/Reward and the cell containig 0,5 is E16
I want the text on the right to change when E16 is changed.

I have tried a coupple of if statements, both using nested if's and AND() statements. But I can't get it to work. On of my test is this:
[image]

My current solution is this:
[image]

Comment: Put another if in the `ELSE` part of the outer `IF`. `if(conditionforgood;"GOOD";if(conditionformediocre;"mediocre";"bad"))`

Comment: `AND(0,5<E16<1)` is not a valid condition. Use `AND(0,5<E16;E16<1)` But actually you don't need that `E16<1` at all, because, when your formula reaches the `ELSE` branch, you already know `E16` must be less than `1` because otherwise it would have chosen the `IF` branch

Comment: You mention you thought about using a vlookup but want to just have an output. This is still possible with a vlookup if you are interested.

    =VLOOKUP(E16,{-1,"bad";0.5,"mediocre";1,"good"},2,TRUE)

This will return:

 - "bad" for -1 <= E16 <0.5
 - "mediocre" for 0.5<= E16 < 1
 - "good" for 1 <= E16

Comment: Use a vlookup() with a table. It is also, imho, easier to edit and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(E16>=1,"Good",IF(E16>=0.5,"Mediocre","Bad"))
```

Or with your regional settings:

```
=IF(E16>=1;"Good";IF(E16>=0,5;"Mediocre";"Bad"))
```

Is this the result you are looking for?

[image]